# What are the responsibilities of .NET developer?

Tags: .net

Many times I see "Looking for .NET Developer" but doesn't specify whether you'll be working with ASP.NET, WPF, Winforms, Silverlight, ADO.NET, etc. By ".NET Developer" do the employers mean a .NET developer that is proficient in all of the above? Isn't that a little too much to know all at once?

Comment: Usually look around the products of the company and you'll get the answer. There is no absolute answer to your first question. The answer to your second question is `NO`. A human being is able to get all these things in mind, Ask Jon Skeet! :-)

Comment: Probably each employer means different things. If the job description is vague, ask for a clarification.

Comment: Jon Skeet? I've heard that name so many times on Stackoverflow. I probably should google him.

Comment: @Rih see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts  I mean he has his own tag on meta for crying out loud! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jon-skeet

Comment: Reading those Jon Skeet facts (Chuck Norris style) just made my day :D

Comment: Jon Skeet made your day? Sounds about right; I heard that he invented time itself. He then invented multi-threading.

Comment: Another decent question bites the dust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

9 times out of 10, I think you're going to find this is a bad agency with a bad client, where neither really knows what they want.

That said, it's possible that they're just thinking that if you know one .NET technology then you can easily pick up the others.  Only you know if that's true for you or not.

I would generally avoid an advert which didn't have specifics, but that statement might change if I needed a job urgently.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time I look through job listings.